# How can I know my chromecast custom receiver is functioning?

Tags: chromecast, receiver

I am trying to cast videos from my html video player to TV via chromecast.
Sender: CastVideos-chrome
https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome
Receiver: CastReferencePlayer (registered as a Custom receiver, hosted on my github,
https://github.com/PhilSSOO/052617_CastReferencePlayer
 and the app ID was input to the sender's CastVideos.js file)
The whole sender folder was put to my server applied from Apache. The path is
C:\Apache24\htdocs\CastVideos-chrome

Putting http//localhost/CastVideos-chrome/ to the address bar of the chrome browser and hit Enter, the app is up and running with videos being cast to TV. Now, my question is: How can I know my custom receiver is functioning? I tried to do some modifications on my css file (receiver app consists of player.html, player.js, player.css) but nothing seemed to be changing on my TV screen.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the [Custom Receiver Application](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver) has to say:

> Note: Google Cast receiver applications must be hosted on secure
>   servers supporting https when published. Publishing a Google Cast
>   receiver application may take several hours to propagate to all Google
>   Cast devices (up to 6 hours). **If you wish to verify that your
>   published application is working properly, you can manually restart
>   your Google Cast device to force a load of new configuration data.**

Check the docs for more details about [Application Configuration](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver#application-configuration).

Answer (score 0):

noogui,

Thank you for your reply.
I purposely modified the CSS file of my custom receiver (styled the progressBar with green color --- rgb(48, 249, 55) --- ), hosted it on my github account, published the receiver, waited 6 h and started testing. Upon starting my sender app the video got cast to TV, and the progressBar is still yellow, NOT GREEN. This means my receiver is not functioning!

I also tried a style receiver, and even styled the progressBar with a wrong color (rgb(48, 249, $$$)). The sender app also cast the video to TV without any complaint. The conclusion is, my receiver is not being called!

I tried to use the Chrome Remote Debugger to debug, but my chromecast device, although showed up on my laptop, didn't have the inspect link with it, so I couldn't go further.

BTW, my sender works fine with default receiver.
I got lost!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out. The issue was related to app hosting.
When a custom receiver is registered to google cast console, the receiver hosting URL and associated sender hosting URL are not where they are stored, but where they are published. For example, the receiver hosting URL
https://github.com/USER/REPOSITORYNAME
is not to be used, but the following URL is 
https://USER.github.io/REPOSITORYNAME......
(this can be accessed via Settings --- GitHub Pages)
Once the correct URL is used, my custom receiver is up and running!
Cheers!